# Getting JSON as string from MySQL using PHP, can we get data as JSON in a field

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing an API using core PHP. When I am returning data, all the fields data are returning as a string, but in some fields I have JSON type of data which is also coming as string

Example:

```
end_city: "mysore",
facilities: "{"Breakfast":false,"PickDrop":true,"Hotel":false,"Guide":true}"
```

Here, field facilities is having JSON, but getting this as a string in the response, want to get this as JSON only not string.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');

// get database connection
require_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate tours object
include_once '../objects/tours.php';

$db = new Database();
$tours = new Tours($db);

$tour = $tours->getTour($_REQUEST["t"]);
$num = $tour->num_rows;

if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = $tour->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
    // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);
} else {
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);
    // tell the user no products found
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No tour found.")
    );
}
```

The exact scenario is, I have one form , after submit that form , I get the JSON data in some fields , after getting the all data I save that in mysql using core php , now I have to display that data on page using angualrjs . Now when I do get request , I get data in the JSON format and all the fields are in the type of string , even JSON fields I am getting as string which create problem.

Comment: i think `http_response_code()` suppose to be before any `echo()`

Comment: No that create no issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is solved and the issue is my data is not saving correctly in the database that's why JSON.parse is not working properly but now issue is solved using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Use **json_decode** to convert a string to json

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: data in not in string format but in mysql query i am getting data as string. I already try json_decode but getting null as data is in right format

Comment: what type of column in the table where is the json stored?

Comment: I am storing data in mysql , and using data type text

Comment: if you save in the text type, then you return the string

Comment: Can you suggest me the valid data type for JSON in mysql

Comment: No, you're keeping it right, in the right type. You just when you choose json from the database, you need to convert the string to json

Comment: Now in MySQL 5.7.8 appeared the type of json. But I have not worked with him yet)

Comment: How can i convert string to JSON in that case

Comment: This will not for me

Comment: You can just return it
        **echo $row;// without json_encode**

Comment: $row is an array , getting array to string conversion error

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the status code and send headers before sending the content.
2. Do not echo multiple json values in the loop, it wouldn't be a valid json response. Collect all results into a list, json_encode it then send that.
3. Set content type to `application/json`

Change:

```php
if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = $tour->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
    // set response code - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);
```

into

```php
header('content-type: application/json');
if ($num > 0) {
    http_response_code(200);
    $results = []
    while ($row = $tour->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
```